# hammer.js - drag event on ipad not fired continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

Dragging with `hammer.js` working fine on desktop browsers. Fired continuously till `dragEnd`. But on iPad it fires only once.

```
hammer(container).on( 'drag', function (e) {_this.onDragging.call(_this, e);}, false );

//onDragStart we init this.start = e.pageX

onDragging : function (e) { 
var diff=this.start-e.pageX;
moveTimeLine(e.pageX);
this.start=e.pageX;
}
```

in order to get smooth Dragging of timeline but the Drag event is only fired one time and not continuously.

`moveTimeLine()` moves timeline by specified pixels so it's taking some time to reflect. and ultimately `dragging` event called only once. Even I do dragging slowly.

**Is there any way drag event fires when user move finger on iPad ?????**

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/458

Just add `e.preventDefault()` to your function and you should be good to go.

EDIT: If the solution is not that easy for you (perhaps you need native scrolling on the vertical axis) have a look at this thread: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/245